# How can i customize shortcuts SourceTree?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I would like to customize some command's shortcuts (like rebase, resolve conflicts, etc), because it is so hard use the mouse many times to run a command.

Comment: Sourcetree essentially wraps the GIT command line. It is possible to learn what commands you want to send and write a script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you cannot customize your own shortcuts.

> Steve Streeting [Atlassian] :
>
> Jun 17, 2013
>
> The shortcuts are not configurable at the moment, sorry!

Source:

https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/180683/is-there-a-way-to-change-keyboard-shortcuts-in-sourcetree

Comment: It is a pity that it is not possible to do this at the moment. I can only wait.

Comment: the fact that it overloads cmd+backspace is so annoying though

Answer (score 0):

If sourcetree is used on windows, you can call ACC to realize shortcut key customization.

I've done that, it's really feasible.